Comparing simplification result by Mathematica with Maple
I use both Maple and Mathematica. Was porting small code from Maple to Mathematica.
In one small computation I noticed this very strange difference and is really serious difference which can affect many things.
I'd like to ask if someone could explain or say which is the correct result. Or at least say if Mathematica's result is correct, then I know Maple's result is wrong.
I do the same exact steps in Maple 2024.1 and Mathematica 14.1
Mathematica gives back answer -1.4142 (or -sqrt(2)) while Maple gives 1.4142
Clearly both answers can't be correct at same time.
It is either Maple is correct or Mathematica is correct. I do not know where else to ask, so thought to ask here.
It is very simple computation actually. I have an expression $f(x)$, which I asked to simplify it with assumption that x<=0, then I tricked the computer and then told it to evaluate the result for x=3. That is all.
Here is the code and the result using Mathematica
ClearAll[x];
e=Sqrt[-2*(x-6)*(2*x-3)]/(x-6);
e1=Assuming[x<=0,Simplify[e]]


e1/.x->3//N

(* -1.41421 *)

The above result also agrees when we replace x by 3 in the original expression before simplifying it:
 e /. x -> 3 // N
 (*-1.41421*)

Now the same exact code in Maple
restart;
e:=sqrt(-2*(x - 6)*(2*x - 3))/(x - 6):
e1:=simplify(e) assuming x<=0;


e1:=evalf(eval(e1,x=3));

gives

See the difference?
Note that Maple gives same result as Mathematica if we replace x by 3 in the original expression
 evalf(eval(e,x=3));
 

gives -1.414213562
So the problem is when simplifying the expression with assumption that x<=0.
I know I should not replace x by 3 in the simplified expression after I told it to simplify it with assumption that x is negative. But this is side-issue. I think both CAS should produce the same result regardless. Right?
Is Mathematica's result the correct one or not?  So I know where to send the bug report to, WRI or Maplesoft :)

You use e1=Assuming[x<=0,Simplify[e]] and  after that you substitute e1/.x->3//N , but 3>0.

I don't really think we can be expected to weigh in on Maple's result. As for Mathematica's result, I can't see any fault in it. It seems like you understand how that result was obtained, so do you actually have a Mathematica question?

Perhaps you're too tired :) . "I think both CAS should produce the same result regardless. Right?" Not necessarily, there exist many expressions with similar complexity that are equivalent only for a range, one simple example I can think of at the moment: Simplify[Power[x, 1/3] == Surd[x, 3], x >= 0] But Simplify won't further simplify them: Simplify[#, x >= 0] & /@ {Power[x, 1/3], Surd[x, 3]}

The Mathematica result has to be correct since it is clearly just an expansion of the product inside the radical (so no potentially branch-cut-bitten transformations were performed). Other issues with this have been noted already-- it seems that there is no viable Mathematica question in this.
